# unwanted loop in Login Form

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, authentication

Hello I got a simple problem but can't find a solution (Friday looking for weekend...)

I have a mainform and a Loginform. My Mainform calls the Loginform in Load. After filling out the Loginform my Login should close and recall the Mainform. But what happens is my Login appears again... Can somebody help me with this code, please:

**Mainform:**

```
using System;
.
.
.
using System.Threading;


namespace HBAPackageConfig
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {


        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            string getcsv = TestCSV();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            runform4();
        }

        private void runform4()
        {
            Form4 loginForm = new Form4();

            // Show the settings form
            loginForm.TopLevel = true;
            loginForm.ShowDialog();
        }
```

**Login:**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HBAPackageConfig
{
    public partial class Form4 : Form
    {
        Form1 mainform = new Form1();

        public Form4()
        {
            InitializeComponent();


        }

        private void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.BringToFront();
            checkBox1.Checked = true;
            txtPass.KeyPress += new KeyPressEventHandler(this.txtPass_KeyPress);



        }

        private void btnLogin_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            loginCheck();
        }


        public void loginCheck()
        {
            //put into the bracket the password,and username you want
            if (txtUser.Text.ToString().CompareTo("Customer") == 0 & txtPass.Text.ToString().CompareTo("Password") == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Login Sucessfull.Click OK to continue", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                this.Hide();     //hide the login form
                mainform.Show();
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Wrong Username/Password! \n Please try again!", "Login", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                txtPass.Text = ""; //delete writed password
                txtUser.Text = ""; //delete writed username
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your main form you are doing this:

- Create Login form
- Show Login form

Then in your login form you are doing this:

- Create Main form
- Show Main form

Hence the infinite cycle.

Your login form doesn't need to create a main form.  There already *is* a main form.  All the login form *should* need to do is close itself, and the main form that's already on the screen should still be there.

If there's more to this that we're not seeing and the existing main form *does* need to be displayed again, that should be done with the *existing* main form and not a new one.  So the login form would need a reference to the main form.

You can accomplish that by adding it to the login form's constructor:

```
Form1 mainform;

public Form4(Form1 mainFormReference)
{
    InitializeComponent();

    this.mainform = mainFormReference;
}
```

Then when invoking the login form from the main form, pass a reference to itself:

```
Form4 loginForm = new Form4(this);
```

That way when the login form does this:

```
mainform.Show();
```

It'll be invoking `.Show()` on the existing main form instead of a new one.

Comment: Thanks David, this was a great explanation!

Answer (score 0):

It appears you've created two instances of `Form1`: the form from which you create and show the login form, and one that's a member variable of the login form.  When a user successfully logs in, you're calling `mainform.Show()` from your login form to show the second instance you've created.  This is not necessary; presumably somewhere in your startup code there's a line like this:

`Application.Run(new Form1());`

The fact that you're getting into the main form's `Load` event handler indicates that it's already in the process of being displayed.  When you return from your login form's `ShowDialog()` method, the initial form will finish loading and display itself.

Comment: nice, short and simple answer! Thank you!

Answer (score -1):

You need a way to let Form1 know that Form4 has already run and the login was successful. You could use caching, or a public property on Form1, or any number of methods.

Then in Form1's Load you only run Form4 if the user has not yet logged in.

Comment: In the OP's code, the login form doesn't close until a successful login is achieved, so the only "notification" that the login form needs to do is closing (hiding) itself.